# Trigger a jenkins project from a web page (worked in 1.9, broken in 2.3)

Tags: jenkins

Our builds generate a webpage which allows the end-user to more easily launch a new build based on the original build. Here's an example:

```
<head>
   <title>Build Links</title>
   <script>
      function runNewBuild()
      {
         xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.open("POST","/view/MyView/job/MyJob/buildWithParameters?Parm1=Razz&Parm2=Zazz");
         xmlhttp.send()
      }
   </script>
</head>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
   <button onClick="runNewBuild()">Run New Build</button>
</form>
```

The html file is stored in and accessed from the build workspace. E.g. the url is:

https://jenkins.myCompany.com:8081/job/MyJob/ws/SomeDir/build_links.html

This worked fine in 1.9, but now fails after upgrading. I fixed some of the issues by setting:

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts;")

But I still get (using chrome inspector):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://jenkins.myCompany.com:8081/view/MyView/job/MyJob/buildWithParameters?Parm1=Razz&Parm2=Zazz.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 403.

Can anyone provide some guidance? Googling tends to bring up stuff related to CORS, but unless I'm missing something...this should not be cross origin.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. There were two necessary steps:

1) Add the CORS plugin with the following settings:

Access-Control-Allow-Origins: https://jenkins.MyCompany.com:8081
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: origin

2) xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken it's that [Content-Security-Policy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) header they added.
Try instead to leave it empty. if you're running it from the command line just loading Jenkins with:

```
 -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"\"
```

Good luck!

Comment: The CSP I set was necessary to fix some initial errors...it works even "less" without that.